# Are health insurance questions off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions on health insurance off-topic?

Example:

> What's the point of declaring a general practitioner ("médecin traitant") in France?
>
> What are the financial consequences not to declare a general practitioner ("médecin traitant") in France? I have a French Social Security as well as a French "mutuel".

Answer (score 6):

I would say those are off-topic questions because the rules and regulations surrounding healthcare vary greatly from country to country and even within regions of some countries. Unless the answer is careful they can very easily give wrong information and have it be hard to spot.

Comment: The example question is clearly about the situation in France.

Comment: Are the rules and regulations the same every where in France? I know that is not true in the United States.

Comment: I guess so (but I'm not an expert on French health law). Anyway, the point I'm trying to make is: As long as the question does not cover all 50 states of the US or all countries of the EU, I'd say it is at least not too broad. If health insurance should be on topic at all is, of course, another question altogether.

Comment: Part of the issue is that the legal requirements can change for someone based on their current situation. As the get older and their legal status changes for instance.  What may be true for a child may not for an adult or senior for example. Or if they have a disability it may change things. There are many factors that can change an answer and that is not even counting law changes.

Comment: @PatrickHoefler - If it is about France, then I would VTC as being too localized.

Comment: @JohnP As far as I can tell, [*too localized* is not a thing anymore](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185102/responding-to-your-too-localized-concerns).

Comment: @JoeW The health laws are pretty much the same across the whole of France, as they are across most EU countries. We don't have states in the same way.

Comment: Well, France isn't federalised; Germany is; the UK is a somewhat special case. It gets tricky. @Tim.