# Revisiting are health care systems and insurance on topic

Tags: discussion

Perhaps I'm the only one that sees some conflict between the meta answer on [insurance](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43/are-health-insurance-questions-off-topic) and [health care systems](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99/are-questions-about-the-health-care-system-on-topic), but to me those two have quite a bit overlap.

In fact on the idea that SE sites are a place where professionals can come and ask technical questions, most of the questions I find myself thinking of asking are in this meeting ground.  Fighting with PICOS always brings up lots of frustration and questions.  Techniques and case examples on getting difficult interventions/treatments approved on insurance/Medicare also come to mind.  I realize the relevance of such questions doesn't extend beyond US boarders, but I don't know if that is sufficient reason to exclude them.  They could be quite helpful within US borders, and I would if they can't be compared to people hacking through cultural settings in programming on SO.

There are a lot of "bureaucratic" kind of questions that might also not follow under the "insurance" umbrella.  For example setting up IRB proposals or trouble shooting cold chain.

---

I guess this is question is partly motivated by my recent read through of the meta section.  I'm trying to think about what serious, professional, medical questions I might ask here.  I'm certainly unlikely to ask about anything I would want a consult on.  I have questions about brand performance and certain tools, but my understanding is that such questions are a poor fit for SE in general.  I want to be involved, but I know that if I don't at least have a little something beneficial drawing me in my participation will be way down.

Thanks to the mods and everyone else working on this, I know you are giving a lot on it.